# Python 3 virtual environment uses default Python's (2.6) socket connections for PyMySQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, virtualenv, pymysql

A server's default Python version is 2.6. Python 3 is also installed and I created a virtual environment (`python3 -m venv py3env`) and installed Flask and PyMySQL within the virtual environment.

However, after the web-server (Apache+WSGI) is configured, the application doesn't work and throws the following error:

```
       File "/var/www/webapp/py3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 90, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
       File "/var/www/webapp/py3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 699, in __init__
  self.connect()
       File "/var/www/webapp/py3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 935, in connect
     self._get_server_information()
       File "/var/www/webapp/py3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1249, in _get_server_information
         packet = self._read_packet()
       File "/var/www/webapp/py3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 991, in _read_packet
         packet_header = self._read_bytes(4)
       File "/var/www/webapp/py3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1025, in _read_bytes
         data = self._rfile.read(num_bytes)

       File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/io.py", line 940, in read
         return self._read_unlocked(n)
       File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/io.py", line 974, in _read_unlocked
         chunk = self.raw.read(wanted)
       File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/io.py", line 591, in read
         n = self.readinto(b)

       File "/var/www/webapp/py3env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/_socketio.py", line 59, in readinto
         return self._sock.recv_into(b)
     TypeError: recv_into() argument 1 must be pinned buffer, not bytearray
```

- I tried installing `python-socketio` via pip but it still isn't being used.
- `MySQL-python` is installed on the server.

How does one force the application to use the Virtual environment's version?

Comment: how is pymysql get installed, and how Apache+WSGI configured to use virutalenv?